# Unable to send eth with the web3 API

Tags: web3js, transactions, nodejs

I'm new to this web3 API and I'm trying to use it with NodeJS. I've not been able to make a single transaction from one address to another. I've been able to successfully retrieve the balance of my address.

The method I'm using is documented [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction) but when I execute the script, it will give an error saying that my params are not formatted well

> Returned error: Invalid params: invalid type: map, expected a 0x-prefixed, hex-encoded vector of bytes.

My params:

```
amount = '0x' + (+web3.utils.toWei('0.06', 'ether')).toString(16)
var rawTx = {
    from: ethAddress,
    to: destinationAddress,
    value: amount 
}
```

The variables `ethAddress` and `destinationAddress` are set correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you generate the rawTx? Are addresses prefixed with '0x'? The link in your question is from web3 1.0 which is in beta and it may have a bug.

Comment: Yes, it's all prefixed with 0x. Everything is in hex format.

Comment: Without something to test with it is impossible to tell. I'd suggest to try with the stable release web3 v0.20, it might be a bug with v1.0.

Comment: Just to be sure, what do I really have to do? I set the provider to be `https://api.myetherapi.com/eth`. That's correct to do right?

Comment: Sorry, but I've never used myetherapi.com previously and can't help with that, perhaps you want to ask a new question about it.